# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy Github Packages

Tags: maven, github, deployment, package, snapshot

I am trying to deploy my artifact as a packaged to Github Packages. On clean deploy I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project cardgame: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.moderatelycomfortablechair:cardgame:jar:0.0.1-20201222.145834-1 from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/ModeratelyComfortableChair/CardGame): Access denied to https://maven.pkg.github.com/ModeratelyComfortableChair/CardGame/org/moderatelycomfortablechair/cardgame/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/cardgame-0.0.1-20201222.145834-1.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml contains the following

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.moderatelycomfortablechair</groupId>
<artifactId>cardgame</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>cardgame</name>
```

...

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub ModeratelyComfortableChair Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/ModeratelyComfortableChair/CardGame</url>
    </repository>
```

My ~/.m2/settings.xml is the same as [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/guides/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#:%7E:text=GitHub%20Packages%20supports%20SNAPSHOT%20versions,xml%20file.), where username and owner is ModeratelyComfortableChair (my github username) and password is a personal access token with repo and read write access.

Comment: The following [link](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/guides/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#:~:text=GitHub%20Packages%20supports%20SNAPSHOT%20versions,xml%20file.) states that I must put the owner as lower case. I've changed my settings and my pom.xml to the following having the OWNER in lowercase, and the OWNER and the REPO in lower case, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to have **read:write** access to **packages** on your Personal Access Token (PAT). That should solve your problem.

This works very well with your private repositories.
However, for those working with organization repositories and having Single Sign-On (SSO) enforced, this might **not be sufficient**. The token must be explicitly authorized for SSO. And Maven command doesn't prompt for that.

There are different ways to authrorize the token, two of which are as explained below.

1. [Easiest] Login to GitHub account and navigate to the PAT section. There you'll find an option to enable SSO for the given token. (Token name could be different in your case)
   [image]
2. Try to clone your repository using Git commandline -
    `git clone https://[USERNAME]:[TOKEN]@[GIT_ENTERPRISE_DOMAIN]/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git`
   It will throw an error and give you a URL for authorizing the token with SSO. Access the URL in a browser and authorize the SSO for the given token. Once authorized, you should be able to publish/deploy your artifacts.
   [image]
   Cheers!